# Sentry doesn't track `OPTIONS` requests

Tags: reactjs, http, fetch, sentry

**TLDR:** How to I make Sentry track `OPTIONS` request in error breadcrumbs?

I'm working on a Next.js project with Sentry configured for error monitoring. I've encountered a weird bug `"Failed to fetch"` with not much additional context and I'm trying to investigate the cause, since no other info is available apart from this message. In my backend API Cloudwatch logs I've noticed, by matching the timestamps, that a `OPTIONS` preflight is sent out and seems to be successful, with status 204, however I see no record in my logs of the actual associated `GET` request being triggered, just the `OPTIONS` one. Keep in mind I can't reproduce this bug myself, everything works fine when I try it out and CORS seems to be correctly configured.

I looked into some replays on sentry trying to get some more info, but noticed the `OPTIONS` request is not logged anywhere. I would like to inspect the response headers of this preflight `OPTIONS` request to see if maybe I get some more info there, so my question is: Is it possible to tell Sentry to track `OPTIONS` requests in error breadcrumbs, the same way that all the other HTTP requests are tracked automatically? I haven't been able to find any documentation on this.

PS. Any other tips on what could be causing this "Failed to fetch" problem are also welcome.

```
Nextjs: v14.0.3
@sentry/nextjs: 7.80.0
react: 18.2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Sentry allows [adding custom breadcrumbs](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/enriching-events/breadcrumbs/#manual-breadcrumbs).

```
// Add a listener on OPTIONS requests and create a breadcrumb.
Sentry.addBreadcrumb({
  message: "OPTIONS request sent",
  level: "info",
  data: ... // Add anything here that you're interested in.
});
```

Here is [Sentry's SDK Breadcrumbs doc](https://develop.sentry.dev/sdk/event-payloads/breadcrumbs/) with more details.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Could you provide some info on how one could create such a listener for `OPTIONS` requests?